# How to remove indent when using \onslide command

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer to present geometry lessons. The problem is that when I use the \onslide command, the lines are indented. As in the example below, line 2, line 3, line 4 are indented. I don't want this, how to fix it. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,tikz}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \onslide<+->{%
                This is a line 1.\\}
            \onslide<+->{%
                This is a line 2.\\}
            \onslide<+->{%
                This is a line 3.\\}
            \onslide<+->{%
                This is a line 4.}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,line width=.6pt] 
                \draw (0,0)--(5,0)--(3,4)--cycle;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No need for `\usetheme{default}`, as the name says, that's loaded by default

Answer (score 2):

It is not an indentation it is a space being interpreted.

Replace `\\}` by `\\}%`

Comment: Oh, I fixed it your way. Thank you so much.